# How can I force a TextView to hide its contents without the natural timeout (as a password)

Tags: java, android

I making something where you are required to enter a pin.

It has four TextView's managed each by its own TextWatcher's that moves Focus to the next TextView.

The TextViews are set to so that it hash's out after each digit:

```
android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

However since these TextViews are separated from each other when entering numbers the previous digits do not hash out in time as each TextView is individual.

Is there a way to force a TextView to hide its contents without the natural timeout (as this normally occurs when entering a second digit).

Answer (score 0):

Any `xyzPassword` inputtype runs a `PasswordTransformatioMethod` which has a `Handler` that posts applying the `Spannable` on the visible characters after ~1.5 seconds, after each `onTextChanged` callback.

Yes, you can force replacing each character with `'\u2022'` span, with your custom `TransformationMethod`. This transformation method will transform characters before they are displayed, so there wouldn't be any delay before they are transformed into bullets.

Comment: I ended up using a little hack by extending the length of each individual TextView from one to two, then on completing the TextView would set the previous TextViews Text to be 2 characters then remove the added character so that it would hash out.